# I'm getting this annoying error on this easy line and how can I fix that? | Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I just started this bot and I'm already getting this error called

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function
```

And this is my index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
var client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () =>{
  console.log("This bot is online ;)")
  client.guilds.get('722098287976513596').channels.get('722098287976513599').send("hello!");
});

client.login(process.env.token);
```

I'm also using heroku to host and I don't see any issues in my code.

Here is the whole error code.

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

```
(node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
var client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () =>{
  console.log("This bot is online ;)")
  client.guilds.cache.get('722098287976513596').channels.get('722098287976513599').send("hello!");
});

client.login(process.env.token);
```

In v12 you must add cache to things like Guild or Members.

Answer (score 0):

Is client.guilds coming up as 'undefined'?

Anyway, try ading `.cache`: `client.guilds.cache.get(serverID)`

"v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods such as Collection#get on data structures like Client#users. You will now have to directly ask for cache on a manager before trying to use collection methods."

Source: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache